# Why isn't my render matching up with renderview mode on blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling, rendering, render-layers

[image]

This picture is in render view mode

[image]

This picture is what happened when  pressed render image.

Comment: To me it looks correct. What's wrong here?

Comment: its missing part of the floor

Comment: i moved part of the grass layer so now it works and i turned off some of the subsurf modifiers so now it works better

Answer (score 0):

If it works by deleting a grass layer, then I suppose the issue comes from the particle's settings. Make sure this option in the particle's render panel is enabled:
[image]